# Passing Razor syntax variable into javascript onclick of an Html Helper

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to render the page, and trigger a notification on button click. I have set this up to just do a pop up for now, since its an internal application for the higher ups.

The button in question is a simple razor syntax html helper with an onclick event to return a confirm dialog. However it seems I am unable to render the item variable for this.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id },
 new { @class = "btn btn-warning", 
 onclick = "return confirm('WARNING: Delete @item.Id?');" })
```

this fails to render item.Id (the output of the surrounding foreach statement but instead outputs the string literal  "@item.Id"

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, 
 new { @class = "btn btn-warning", 
 onclick = "return confirm('WARNING: Delete ' + item.Id + '?');" })
```

This renders the variable but since it is not a javascript variable it renders as  "Delete undefined ?"

How can I use a variable from the foreach outside of the javascript passed into this dialog, to make the message more descriptive.

Comment: Do string concatenation in onclick event

Comment: Bhuban thanks for the insight that is what I am trying to get to, however I cannot for the life of me remember/find the syntax can you elaborate with an example

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my own problem using `string.Format` in `C#`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, 
 new { @class = "btn btn-warning", 
 onclick = string.Format("return confirm('WARNING: Delete {0}?');", item.Id) })
```

Comment: The reason you had to do it that way, is that you had already switched to "code" mode by starting a line with @.   The razor compiler never even saw the @item.

Comment: Dave: makes perfect sense, Thank you for the details, hopefully this saves someone the far too long I spent on a stupid error

Comment: @Dave or as in my answer for their second example they were including a javascript variable instead of their `foreach` variable since the string wasn't concatenated correctly. Two ways to cut the cake.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your string properly. Try the following:

```
onclick = "return confirm('WARNING: Delete " + item.Id + "?');"
```

Your error is saying the javascript item `item.Id` is not defined because `item` is probably not defined in your js scripts.